# Loaded jQuery UI library but getting "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Trying to make the #intro_title bounce when the document is ready. I loaded both the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries and I still get "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function". I suspect that this is an issue with importing the jQuery UI library so...

I tried loading the libraries at the end of the body, head, html, etc. and changed "src" to "href" but I get the same result each time. I even tried both Google's and jQuery's hosted libraries only to meet the same result.

lodge_101.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lodge_101_main.css">
<head>
    <title>Scipio Lodge 101</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="intro_title">WELCOME TO LODGE 101</h1>


<script src="lodge_101_main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

lodge_101_main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#intro_title").effect("bounce", { times:3 }, "slow");
});
```

Why does this continue to happen and how can I fix it? I'm still new to programming so please be very critical of my work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you have to load the jquery library before the jquery ui. just change your script tags  position. move the jquery script tag at the first position.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `jquery` before `jquery-ui`.